# Exporting folding a cube animation in MD5 format

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, armature

I am new to blender so kindly ignore the typos or some irrelevant technical terms.My problem is I have created a cube whose faces I have separated (Check the screenshot for a clear picture). Now I want to fold the faces back to cube. I have tried animating the folding of cube and its running successfully in blender but when I tried to export it to MD5 format the animation it is not working in Unity. The complete animation is not coming as one whole animation but it is coming parts. Below I have attached the screenshots of the properties of the animation.

This is the hierarchy structure of Armature and cube faces
[image: This is the hierarchy structure of Armature and cube faces]

This is the animation in action. You can see the keyframes below
[image: This is the animation in action. You can see the keyframes below]

Please help me.

Comment: This is not working? https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/IdTech4_md5 and this https://sourceforge.net/p/blenderbitsbobs/wiki/MD5%20exporter/ (not tested on my side)

Comment: I am using iTech4 script. but it is not exporting this animation. Any other tutorial where I can learn how to animate folding cube and export in MD5